# how to send modeldata and currenttime from view to controller action using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have written following code to send modeldata and currenttime to controller action.what is the correct way to pass it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    timeClock = setInterval("TimeTick()", 10);
    SwipeIn(); SwipeOut();

    $('#btnswipeIn').click(function () {

        clearTimeout(swipeinId);

        var ptime = $("#swipeIn").text();

        alert(ptime);

        var url = "EmployeeDashBoard/Index/";

        $.post(url, { model: $("#dashboard").serialize(), time: ptime }, function (result) { $('#time').html(resul.time) });


    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to pass to send modeldata and currenttime to controller action is as follows:

```
$(function () { 

    $("#proedtbtn").click(function () { 
window.location.href = "/Controller/ActionName/" + parameter1 + "?parameter2=" + parameter2.val + "&parameter3=" + parameter3.val;
    });
});
```

Here **proedbtn** is the submit button used in view. Instead of **parameters** mentioned you can place whatever values you want to send to controller action like **time** etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  timeClock = setInterval("TimeTick()", 10);
  SwipeIn(); SwipeOut();

  $('#btnswipeIn').click(function () {

    clearTimeout(swipeinId);

    var ptime = $("#swipeIn").text();

    alert(ptime);

    var url = "EmployeeDashBoard/Index/";

    var data = $("#dashboard").serializeArray();
    data.push({name: 'time', value: ptime});

    $.post(url, data, function (result) { $('#time').html(result.time); });
  });
});
```